# Как установить mono на Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, mono

Пробовал `sudo apt-get install -f`, но по любому не пашет. Версия Debian 7.9. Репозиторий брал на офф сайте(правда там был для 8,0)

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: У mono не дурная документация и есть репозитории для дебиана http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

P.s. Не указана версия Debian, версия mono, которую пытаетесь установить. Откуда брали мануал по установке.

Comment: поправил,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил первый же репозиторий из документации. У меня тоже Wheezy стоит. Смотрим версии пакетов:

```
root@alpha:~# apt-cache policy mono-devel
mono-devel:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1
    Version table:
      4.2.1.102-0xamarin1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
      2.10.8.1-8+deb7u1 0
        500 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages

root@alpha:~# apt-cache policy mono-complete
mono-complete:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1
    Version table:
      4.2.1.102-0xamarin1 0
         500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
      2.10.8.1-8+deb7u1 0
        500 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
root@alpha:~# apt-cache policy libmono-cil-dev
libmono-cil-dev:
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: 4.2.1.102-0xamarin1
    Version table:
       4.2.1.102-0xamarin1 0
          500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
       2.10.8.1-8+deb7u1 0
          500 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
          500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Как видно версии пакетов вполне удовлетворяют запросам. Вот репозиторий, который я добавил:

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
```

Может быть Вы где-то ошиблись или не допоняли документацию?